# Windows Admin Center - Remote Desktop only works from inside LAN

Tags: windows, windows-admin-center

I have successfully setup Windows Admin Center and everything works as epected from within the LAN. I forwarded the ports through my gateway and attempted remote access. Everything works as expected, I am able to view all tabs I try, but when I try remote desktop, it doesn't work. I tried connecting to both the server and VM consoles to no avail. It just shows a blank screen where the console should be (usually I get an Auth pop-up on the right hand side).

Any ideas on what to adjust or places I can share/look for debugging information?

Update: More Details

I have a Windows 10 LTSC 2019 client running Hyper-V w/ 2 Windows Server Core 2019 DC. One runs WAC (Gateway-Server) the other a DC. I'm currently adding computers to Domain to see if this helps resolve anything. There is another Ubuntu VM as well.

Settings:

- Enabled RDP on machines
- Disabled requirement for Network Level Auth
- Proper SSL Certs installed on all machines

Things I have tried:

- Powershell in WAC --> Works
- Overview/Registry etc --> Works
- VM Overview & Inventory --> Works
- RDP to VM (Windows/Liunx) or Host OS --> Do not work, no "Auth Pop-up" on right hand side, just blank/hanging.

  - Confirmed working correctly from within LAN

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that obviously makes sense as Remote Desktop is bound to be limited by the limitations of - RDP.

Install an RDP gateway (a server program) and configure your local RDP settings to redirect nonlocal traffic to this gateway and it should work ;)

Comment: Are you sure this makes sense? I thought the way WAC operated the RDP session acted as if it was "local" between the wac installation and the console. Regardless, I'll try your suggestion, but it will take a bit to confirm.

Comment: Nope, to my knowledge it starts RDP on the client side. While RDP traffic can relay over HTTP, i would really wonder if they did rebuild the whole of RDP gateway in WAC.

Comment: I do know that my work lan where I am testing blocks RDP outbound, but like, what if you accessed WAC from a client without RDP like Linux? This is why I figured it was "client agnostic". Also, I'm only a little familiar with all this, but I do know a recent big feature was WinRM over HTTPS for WAC.

Comment: THen it may not work? I mean, you still have WAC, but you really now ask for a RDP client in JAVASCRIPT? SERIOUSLY? RDP is extremely complicated, must be for performance. I coubt a Linux/Javascript client could even draw the screen fast enough.